# Как правильнее будет сохранять массив данных после изменений его представления в виде HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, хранение-данных

Я хочу сделать html список `ul>li`, где в каждой `li` будет карточка с данными, которые поступают из стороннего API средствами чистого JavaScript(ES6). 
В последствии эти карточки могут удаляться, меняться местами (drag&drop) или обновляться свежими данными из API по пользовательским события.

Если просто описать алгоритм, то получается:

*Первый вход на сайт > получение данных из API > изменение данных > нажал на кнопку "сохранить" > измененный объект записался в localstorage и следующие входы читаются уже оттуда.*

И вот меня заинтересовал вопрос, как правильнее будет сделать это сохранение состояния изменений. 
В голове крутиться несколько вариантов:

1. Изменять исходный массив объектов при каждом изменении в ul.
2. При нажатии кнопки "сохранить" проходить по всем карточкам и собирать данные в новый массив объектов, который потом сохранять.
3. Взять просто в текстовом виде разметку потомков UL и сохранить.

Я думаю, что это частая задача. Подскажите пожалуйста, что называется, лучшие практики. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Самый легкий в реализации - второй вариант.

Comment: "Легкий" в данном случае синоним - "оптимальный"? Мне почему-то кажется, что есть вариант о котором я не подумал и он закроет все пункты требований. Чтобы и расширяемость и по скорости хорошо работал и можно было всякие фичи добавлять, типо фильтров по карточкам.

Comment: Легкий - значит легкий в реализации для набора действий *удаляться, меняться местами (drag&drop) или обновляться свежими данными из API по пользовательским события.*.Оптимальность будет зависеть от конкретного набора требований к функционалу, а не *можно было всякие фичи добавлять*. Но третий вариант даже не рассматривайте :)